# Почему не срабатывает метод save()

Tags: php, yii2

вот сам код

```
$wath= Watch::findOne(['id'=>$user, 'id_serial'=>$get["delete"]]);
            $wath->active=0;
            $wath->save();
```

пишет `Call to undefined method stdClass::save()`

Comment: А вы уверены, что `Watch::findOne` находит запись, что бы ее можно было потом сохранить?

Comment: Отметьте тогда как решение мой ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Watch::findOne(['id'=>$user, 'id_serial'=>$get["delete"]]);` не находит запись, что бы ее можно было потом сохранить.